# How to remove frontend/web from url in Yii2 advanced so that it doesn't appear when I use Url::to

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have written .htaccess files to prevent frontend/web from appearing in url but when I saet  links through Url::to it appears in url.
This is my .htaccess in root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # deal with admin first
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
    RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
    RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images)
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

This is .htaccess file in frontend/web directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Please help me I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Hi, give an example of url (result of Url::to) and part you don't want to appear in it

Comment: Url::to dosn't care what you write in htaccess. It uses UrlManager to produce url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following configuration in Apache's httpd.conf file or within a virtual host configuration. Note that you should replace `path/to/frontend/web` with the actual path for `frontend/web`.

```
# Set document root to be "frontend/web"
DocumentRoot "path/to/frontend/web"

<Directory "path/to/frontend/web">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # ...other settings...
</Directory>
```

[Yii2 Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#recommended-apache-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: I have written .htaccess files properly I just forgot to add baseUrl=>'' in config file.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in to your .htaccess file and replace /to/base/path/ with your project directory path

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/to/base/path/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of questions about basic stuff. what about [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1xtFbO9jgQ&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF)
And you can see in them a lot of stuff  for ccs and not only