# Yii removing app name from URL without change directory files

Tags: mod-rewrite, yii

My Yii is set up like this

```
/webroot/app
```

The app folder hosts the yii application

How do I remove the 'app' portion from the URL.
Thanks for any help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove frontend/web from url in Yii2 advanced so that it doesn't appear when I use Url::to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805855/how-to-remove-frontend-web-from-url-in-yii2-advanced-so-that-it-doesnt-appear-w)

Comment: Is this applicable for Yii?

Comment: Its apache config, nothing to do with yii